# Perl: информация о файле

Tags: файлы, perl

Данный код выводит размер файла `file.txt`, как реализовать ввод имени файла с клавиатуры?

```
$filename = "file.txt";  
($dev, $ino, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size, $atime,  
     $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat ($filename);  
print "$filename is $size bytes long.";
```

Comment: perl не умеет клавиатуру. он умеет stdin и интерфейсы к библиотекам gtk/qt/readline/ncurses. вам как надо ?

Comment: через `$filename = <>;`

Comment: @KoVadim про chomp не надо забывать.

Comment: да, он бывает очень полезным.

Answer (score 1):

```
chomp($filename = <STDIN>) ;
($dev, $ino, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size, $atime,  
 $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat ($filename);  
print "$filename is $size bytes long.";
```